# Routing in .htaccess with regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to perform routing in .htaccess with regex. I have multiple URLs like the following:

```
/catagory/page/id/token/pagenumber
/catagory/page/id/token
/catagory/page/id
/catagory/page
/catagory
```

I want the catagory, page and other parameters to be set as follows:

```
catagory = "catagory"
page = "page"
params = "id/token/pagenumber"
```

I have tried something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([\d\w]+)[/]*([\d\w]+).|^([\d\w]+)? index.php?catagory=$1&page=$2&params=$3 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]*)(?:/(.*))?)?/?$ /index.php?controllerName=$1&methodName=$2&params=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: i think i can work on this. 
http://gap.guvenaltuntas.com/mycategory/mypage/6 is my test url is working. but http://gap.guvenaltuntas.com/mycategory/mypage/6/5 is not working. Thanks anyway

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]*)(?:/(.*))?)?/?$ /index.php?controllerName=$1&methodName=$2&params=$3 [QSA,L] i have changed one of your lines please update it. and thanks for help.

Answer (score -2):

use this

```
RewriteRule ^\/([\w\d]+)\/([\w\d]+)\/(.*)$ index.php?catagory=$1&page=$2&params=$3 [NC,L]
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/sL9rR7

if thats not working then you can try this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\/([\w\d]+)\/([\w\d]+)\/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^http://yourdomain.com$ http://yourdomain.com/index.php?catagory=%1&page=%2&params=%3
```

Comment: thanks for your answer your regex is working thats true. But mine working too. My problem is in .htaccess file parameters not working these regexes.